# Electron js desktop app not showing even after calling show() function on new window

Tags: javascript, windows, electron

I am new to Electron js, but when I run `npm run start` on the command line, the window seems to show sometimes, but also doesn't show sometimes. I have no idea what is wrong. I even tried removing the `show : false` part on the newly created `BrowserWindow` but, the same problem still occurs after running `npm run start` a few more time. When I package the app using Electron-packager I still face same problem

**Edit:** I found out that when I removed all the code in the renderer.js file, it works perfectly, but when I put the code back, it produces that problem, so probably the problem lies in the renderer process

In .app/main.js

```
  // const {menu_template, save_as_id} = require('./app-menu');
    const {app, BrowserWindow, Menu, dialog, ipcMain} = require('electron');
    const path = require('path');
    
    /**
     * Create a new window when called
     */
    function createWindow() {
      let x; // Window x cordinate or horizontal position on screen
      let y; // Window y cordinate or vertical position on screen
    
      if (BrowserWindow.getAllWindows().length >= 3) return;
    
      const focusedWindow = BrowserWindow.getFocusedWindow();
      if (focusedWindow) {
        let [posX, posY] = focusedWindow.getPosition();
        // Log the window position
        console.log(`   Window position
                    x : ${posX}, y : ${posY}`);
    
        if (!focusedWindow.isNormal())
          posX = posY = 50;
        // Randomly place the window on the screen
        const randX = Math.round(Math.random() * 20);
        const randY = Math.round(Math.random() * 20);
        const _randX = -randX - 5;
        const _randY = -randY - 5;
    
        x = posX + (randX <= 10 ? _randX : randX);
        y = posY + (randY <= 10 ? _randY : randY);
        // check if window is not fully visible
        const isOffScreen = x < 0 || y < 0;
        // then set the window in a specific position: 60
        if (isOffScreen)
          x = y = 60;
      }
    
      // Create a new browser window
      let newWindow = new BrowserWindow({
        x,
        y,
        minWidth: 300,
        minHeight: 300,
        show: false,
        webPreferences: {
          enableRemoteModule: true,
          nodeIntegration: true,
          preload: path.join(__dirname, 'preload.js')
        }
    
      });
    
      newWindow.on('closed', () => {
        newWindow = null;
      });
    
      newWindow.loadFile('./app/index.html');
      newWindow.once('ready-to-show', () => {
        // now show the current window, when GUI has been loaded to the   window
        newWindow.show();
        console.log('Window ready to show');
    
        // set the window title to indicate that the current file is unnamed
        // and needs to be saved
        newWindow.setTitle('Untitled - NoteEditor');
      });
    }
    
    // Create new window on application first startup
    app.whenReady().then(() => {
    //   Menu.setApplicationMenu(menu_template);
      createWindow();
    })
    
    /**
     * Simply sets the `targetWindow`'s title, to `title`
     * @param {*} targetWindow to recipient for title change
     * @param {*} title the new title of window
     */
    const setWindowTitle = (targetWindow, title) =>      targetWindow.setTitle(title);
    
    exports.createWindow = createWindow;
    // exports.chooseFile = chooseFile;
    exports.setWindowTitle = setWindowTitle
```

In ./app/renderer.js

```
 const {ipcRenderer, remote} = require("electron");
const mainProcess = remote.require('./main.js');
const app = remote.app;

var text = document.getElementById('text'); // The TextArea
var initialTextContent;
var g_targetTitle;


// when a key is pressed, display status showing that text has been edited and needs to be saved
text.addEventListener('keyup', () => {
  const target = remote.getCurrentWindow();
  let changedIndicatorChar = '*';
  let _windowTitle = target.getTitle();
  let isWindowStartUp = _windowTitle.startsWith('Untitled');

  // revert the window title to initial title if changes were removed
  if (text.value == initialTextContent)
    mainProcess.setWindowTitle(target, g_targetTitle);

  // should not set window title again based on this constraints  
  if (!isWindowStartUp && !_windowTitle.startsWith('*') && !_windowTitle.endsWith('txt')) {
    let newWindowTitle = changedIndicatorChar + _windowTitle;
    mainProcess.setWindowTitle(target, newWindowTitle);
  }
});
```

In ./app/index.html

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <title>Note Editor</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    </head>
    
    <body>
        <textarea id="text"></textarea>
    </body>
    <script src="./renderer.js"></script>
    
    </html>
```

Comment: Hi there! Interesting problem! Could you please reduce the code in your question as much as possible, while still showing the problematic behavior? As it stands right now, it needs to be modified by people willing to help before it even runs. See [example], and [edit] the question.

Comment: In practice, this likely means to make a separate "project" on your machine, dump the code, remove everything that's not needed, check if the error is still there.. then repeat.. until you have the absolute minimum of lines that reproduce the issue you see. More often than not, you'll even find the error yourself doing that :)

Comment: @snwflk, I reduced the code to only the function where I create a new window, please I need help, I have been stuck with this for a very long time.

Comment: May I ask you to in fact make a separate project? You have greatly reduced the code, but there are still remnants of the old code, and it won't run. Please, *please make a standalone project to drill the code down to the absolute minimum, while still runnable*

Comment: Oh, Ok I will do that now

Comment: @snwflk I did as you said, and found out that when I added the renderer.js code to the program, the window stops showing, but without it, it shows every time. I will update the code now

Comment: You're on a good track - you know more than in the beginning. Now delete everything from renderer.js step-by-step until you find the culprit. Please take this to your heart: remove everything that is not needed for other people to help you. For example: is the CSS really needed to show the error? Reduce the code! That is *your* job! :)

Comment: @snwflk I have reduced the code even further, but it still hangs. I don't even think I can reduce the code further

Comment: There are a lot of issues with your code, but I am putting a comment in hopes when I have time I'll be able to help steer you in a better direction. In the meantime continue to try! I don't know how long it will be until I can write this out.

Comment: @Zac thanks, am waiting

Comment: @EbenmeluNoah I replied.

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend you read my [introduction to electron](https://github.com/reZach/secure-electron-template/blob/master/docs/newtoelectron.md) post first, as it's good knowledge.

A few things are biting you here:

1. Your new windows you are creating are getting garbage collected because `let newWindow` is in `function createWindow()`. You'll want to store a reference to these windows *outside* this function. [An example](https://github.com/reZach/secure-electron-template/blob/master/app/electron/main.js#L25-L27).
2. I don't recommend using `remote` or `nodeIntegration`. These are *old* ways of doing things that are prone to security problems. [This post](https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/9920#issuecomment-575839738) has some good information too.

Here's a stab at what you are trying to do, use this as a starting point. It doesn't quite handle multiple windows, but I think you can expand on this to get you started!

**main.js**

```js
const {
  app,
  BrowserWindow,
  ipcMain
} = require("electron");
const path = require("path");

// Keep a global reference of the window object, if you don't, the window will
// be closed automatically when the JavaScript object is garbage collected.
let win;

async function createWindow() {

  // Create the browser window.
  win = new BrowserWindow({
    width: 800,
    height: 600,
    webPreferences: {
      nodeIntegration: false, // is default value after Electron v5
      contextIsolation: true, // protect against prototype pollution
      enableRemoteModule: false, // turn off remote
      preload: path.join(__dirname, "preload.js") // use a preload script
    }
  });

  // Load app
  win.loadFile("./app/index.html");

  // Emitted when the window is closed.
  win.on("closed", () => {
    // Dereference the window object, usually you would store windows
    // in an array if your app supports multi windows, this is the time
    // when you should delete the corresponding element.
    win = null;
  });

  win.once("ready-to-show", () => {
    // now show the current window, when GUI has been loaded to the window
    win.show();
    console.log("Window ready to show");
    
    // set the window title to indicate that the current file is unnamed
    // and needs to be saved
    win.setTitle("Untitled - NoteEditor");
  });
}

app.on("ready", createWindow);

ipcMain.on("toMain", (event, args) => {
  win.setTitle(args);
});
```

**preload.js**

```js
const {
    contextBridge,
    ipcRenderer
} = require("electron");

// Expose protected methods that allow the renderer process to use
// the ipcRenderer without exposing the entire object
contextBridge.exposeInMainWorld(
    "api", {
        changeTitle: (title) => {
            ipcRenderer.send("toMain", title);
        }
    }
);
```

**index.html**

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en-US">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
    <script>
        // Update the title of the window
        window.api.changeTitle("new title");
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks @Zac, answer was extremely useful. I am sorry I couldn't send you feedback soon enough.But I think enabling remote and nodeIntegration was the problem. BTW, I continued building my app with ease now. I will post the code soon on how I corrected my flaws.

Comment: But I have a question. I had to put almost all my renderer process code in preload.js because document object doesn't work in renderer.js, when I use the method you suggested. So my question is, is there even any use of renderer js code, when I can equally do it in preload ?

Comment: But I have a question. I had to put almost all my renderer process code in preload.js because document object doesn't work in renderer.js, when I use the method you suggested. So my question is, is there even any use of renderer js code, when I can equally do it in preload ?

Comment: @EbenmeluNoah I'm glad I can help! What do you mean by document object?

Comment: I am new to javascript, but I was referring to the DOM object.

Comment: @EbenmeluNoah do you mean `window`? `window` works in renderer.js. Are you using Typescript by chance?

Comment: no, I am using Javascript. And no, it is not window. I mean document, example document.querySelectorAll('p');

Comment: @EbenmeluNoah `document` should work in any renderer.js file you have. I might suggest posting another question here on SO since it's kind of deviating from the original question.

Answer (score 0):

This may be unrelated to the problem of the window not always showing up, but in any case, the variable `newWindow` must be declared outside the function `createWindow()`, otherwise the `BrowserWindow` object it represents won't remain valid (i.e., will get garbage-collected) after the function is exited from...

```
let newWindow = null; // Declaration moved out of createWindow()

function createWindow() {
  // [...]
  // Create a new browser window
  newWindow = new BrowserWindow({
    x,
    y,
    minWidth: 300,
    minHeight: 300,
    show: false,
    webPreferences: {
      enableRemoteModule: true,
      nodeIntegration: true,
      preload: path.join(__dirname, 'preload.js')
    }
  });
  // [...]
}
```